# Code formatting lost, unable to save plugins in PhpStorm EAP 2016.3

Tags: phpstorm

I recently updated to PhpStorm EAP 2016,3. and in the process, it seems that all of my code editor settings have been lost. When I opened a project with Drupal `.module` files, all syntax highlighting was lost and when I looked in the File Types settings, `.module` and `.inc` files were not listed for "PHP File (syntax Highlighting Only)". I added them in, but even then all my font color settings are gone.

If I open a .php file, I get a message saying that "Plugins supporting *.php files are found", but when I click on the "Enable PHP plugin" and go to the Plugins window, the PHP plugin is enabled, but when I click on OK, I get a message saying "Cannot Save Settings: Unable to apply changes: plugins "PHP Remote Interpreter", "Drupal Symfony Bridge", "PHP Docker", "SSH Remote Run" won't be able to load."

Is there a config file I can restore from a Time Machine backup to fix this? Or do I have to manually set my editor settings again?

Thanks.

Comment: You may delete 2016.3 settings (all together) when IDE is closed and on next launch it will ask if you want to import settings from previous (2016.2 or whatever other version you have had before). This is, of course, if you have not deleted them yet. For locations see this link: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: I did that and restored from 2016.2 settings, but it looks like the core issue is the PHP plugin is disabled, and when I attempt to enable it, the settings changes can't be saved. My error log shows multiple plugins that cannot be enabled because the PHP plugin can't be enabled (which seems odd for an app created primarily for PHP).

Comment: TBH -- no idea. I've been using EAP builds since v1 .. and never seen anything like you describing (but I'm on Windows .. and your case could be Mac-specific). One possible thing though: try with all 3rd party (not bundled by default) plugins disabled. Other than that -- submit support ticket -- they may have seen similar cases elsewhere -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: BTW -- What do you mean by "PHP File (syntax Highlighting Only)" file type? I have never seen such stuff in PhpStorm. Some screenshot + `idea.log` would be great to see

Comment: @wonder95 did you manage to solve this problem? I've got the same message.